# Pass UserDefined Table type Parameter from controller

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-web-api, controller

I am asking this question second time but still I did not got an answer.
I want to execute a stored procedure that has a user-defined table type in a Web API controller.

Here is code for the controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostTableForDTProductCodePO([FromBody] List<TableForDTProductCodePO> tableForDTProductCodePO)
    {
      DataTable dtable = ToDataTable(tableForDTProductCodePO); // I am getting correct data in DataTable
        using (InspectionDBEntities dbCon = new InspectionDBEntities())
        {
            var response = dbCon.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC dbo.ConsolidateInspection @TblConsolidation", dtable);
                dbCon.SaveChanges();
                return Ok("Done");
        }
    }
```

In above code I tried to create SqlParameter and pass Table Data but still it did not work, here is what I tried

```
//SqlParameter tDataParam = new SqlParameter(); // pass tDataParam  instead dtable
                //tDataParam.ParameterName = ("@TblConsolidation");
                //tDataParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                //tDataParam.Value = dtable;
                //tDataParam.TypeName = "dbo.DTProductCodePO";
```

Here is SQL Query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ConsolidateInspection ]
@TblConsolidation DTProductCodePO READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableForDTProductCodePO SELECT * FROM @TblConsolidation

END
```

I am getting no error, but the data is not added to the database. From Postman, I am getting right data in the controller parameters.

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: "EXEC dbo.ConsolidateInspection @TblConsolidation" and the Sp name "[dbo].[InsertValueToTableForDTProductCodePO]' is different any idea? Are you executing the right sp?

Comment: They are same , actually I copied answer from previous post.. I edited answer for you

Comment: Any Update/Help?